# Error accessing field [private int in Springboot data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is entity class , I simply want to save this entity but when I am trying to hit the api I am getting error as given below , I am pretty much sure it is due some mapping issue , any sort of help is appreciated :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "productpurchasedata")
public class Test {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "customerid")
        private int customerid;
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
        @Column(name = "mailid")
        private String mailid;
        @Column(name = "address")
        private String address;
        @Column(name = "city")
        private String city;
        @Column(name = "state")
        private String state;
        @Column(name = "postalcode")
        private String postalcode;
        @Column(name = "mobileno")
        private long mobileno;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Test.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
        @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", referencedColumnName = "customerid", insertable=false, updatable=false) })
        private PurchaseDetails purchasedetails;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Test.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "customerid")
        private List<ProductPurchased> productpurchased;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Test.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
        @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", referencedColumnName = "customerid", insertable=false, updatable=false) })
        private PaymentHistory paymenthistory;
```

Error:

```
 "message": "Error accessing field [private int com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.Test.customerid] by reflection for persistent property [com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.Test#customerid] : com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.PaymentHistory@7659b9; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.Test.customerid] by reflection for persistent property [com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.Test#customerid] : com.bhushan.spring.files.excel.model.PaymentHistory@7659b9",
```

Comment: Add query for which you are getting this error.

Comment: I am not adding any query , I am just simply using save method from JPARepository Interface

Comment: Add your setter getter name for customerId

Comment: And ping the hibernate version are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You relationship look like wrong I guess. Because one user have many payment history and purchase details not other way round.
Many user doesn't have same same history.

```
@ManyToOne
  private PurchaseDetails purchasedetails;
 
  @ManyToOne
   private PaymentHistory paymenthistory
```